# Show past emails in android EditText while entering emails?

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` like this:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/txt_login_username"
     android:layout_width="300dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/pengala_logo"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_login_pwd"
     android:ems="10"
     android:hint="Please enter Email"
     android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
     android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
     android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I want to show all email ids as suggestion when a user starts typing in the `EditText`. Similar to this

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: All values are static ? dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that use [Autocomplete TextView](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2012/10/using-autocomplete-textview.html).

When user enter `userName` in `Autocomplete TextView` and press login you need to store username in sharedpreferences. For sharedpreferences see [This tutorial](http://androiddevelopmentworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/shared-preferences-in-android.html).

Select entred values from sharedpreferences and display it in your Autocomplete TextView when user comes again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [library](https://github.com/KeithYokoma/AccountAutoCompleteEditText) for achieving this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<jp.yokomark.widget.account.autocomp.AccountAutoCompleteEditText
    android:id="@+id/any"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label_account_type_any"
    app:accountType="any"/>
```

AccountAutoCompleteEditText has a custom attribute of accountType. This attribute accepts any of the following value.

```
Value       Meaning
any         Show the candidate account of all type.
email       Show the candidate account using email address.
phoneNumber Show the candidate account using phone number.
```

By this you can easily use it